# How to access a function from a library with underscore?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to use a function _kendall_dis from library scipy.stats. I try to use

```
scipy.stats._kendall_dis
```

or

```
from scipy.stats import _kendall_dis
```

but they don't work.
Also, seems it is in Cython, so I can't simply copy and paste the code into my code.

Comment: By convention such functions should be treated as private. Is there no regular function that does what you want?

Comment: No, I searched but didn't find

Comment: `from scipy import stats` might enable  you to use `stats._kendall_dis`.

Comment: Doesn't work: "module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute '_kendall_dis'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_kendall_dis` is an attribute of `_stats` and not `stats`. To verify that, take a look at the source code of [stats.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py). So you need to use this: `from scipy.stats._stats import _kendall_dis`